# Android listview can not listen on selected item

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, focus, listener

I met a problem where i can not listen on a single item selection from the listView.
Here is my xml layout structure for this page.

```
RelativeLayout
    LinearLayout
        searchText
        searchButton
    LinearLayout
        list
```

Below is the code about how to fetch data from text and how i set listener for list view.

```
private void searchAction() {
    TextView searchText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.searchText); 
    String userName = searchText.getText().toString(); 
    searchText.clearFocus();
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.search_list_item, 
            null, 
            new String[]{},  
            new int[]{},
            0);
    adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() { 
        @Override
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            switch(view.getId()) {
            // here can add one more line in the main page for each account
            return false;
        }
    }); 
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.requestFocus(); 
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int index, long id) { 
            //String str=listView.getItemAtPosition(index).toString(); 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Index: "+index + "ID: "+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            return true;
        }
    });
    listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
}
```

I am able to fetch data from textView. But the listener i set for listView does not work. 
Any help will be accepted. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? What's the expected behaviour? What's happening? Here you're setting a Longclick listener to the entire listView, not each separate item of the list. Is that what you want?

Comment: I am trying to listen on a single item click action from the listView.

Comment: inside the onItemLongClick function. I am able to get the index of the selected item. hence i can do more actions with the corresponding item.

Comment: Then what you need is an Adapter, where you'll be able to manage the behaviour for each child. See a complete example here : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#androidlists_adapterintro

Comment: Inside my code, I set adapter first. is that u want?

Comment: Did you read the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way you tried only happens when you long click on each row of list not it's children.
you should implement OnClickListener in your adapter class for managing clicks on each child.